# Generating thumbnail from original bitmap string received on PHP server

Tags: php, encoding, bitmap

I'm sending a full size bitmap (500x500) in base 64 string to a PHP server. When I received the data, I want to decode it and generate two JPEGS: one in the original size, and one smaller (thumbnail). Here's my original code:

```
<?php
    $base=$_POST['originalImage']; // Bitmap in 500x500
    $binary=base64_decode($base);

        // ?? How to generate binary for bitmap in 200x200?
?>
```

Comment: I would then save it as an image on the server, and then use a pre-written thumbnail library that would do a better job than I could in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save that binary string to the server as a file and then do a google search. You'll find  tons of tutorials that also include sample code you can copy and paste like that one http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php

If you want to do it properly I suggest you to use https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine which is a very nice php 5.3 OOP image manipulation lib that works with different engines.

Here is a dead easy sample for thumbnail generation with Imagine:

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
// or
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
// or
$imagine = new Imagine\Gmagick\Imagine();

$size    = new Imagine\Image\Box(40, 40);

$mode    = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
// or
$mode    = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;

$imagine->open('/path/to/large_image.jpg')
    ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
    ->save('/path/to/thumbnail.png')
;
```